# How can I stop Dogmeat from following me in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

How do I permanently keep Dogmeat away ?

I can tell him to stay somewhere but as soon as I change zone he's teleported to me. I can set his home with a workshop to Sanctuary for example but I think that's only where to find him if I lose him.

Comment: Have you tried putting him into a dog house? You can build one and also find one in Sanctuary. Maybe this will be his command to stay as long as you pick him up again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "stop following you". You can communicate with him (press the talk button) and tell him to stay. You can also tell him to go to a dog house if one exists (or build one for him if one doesn't although there is one in Sanctuary). This will get him to stop following you until you next fast travel.

[image: dogmeat in a doghouse]

If you want him to actually leave you alone so you can continue on your journey without a companion, you need to speak to him and select the "Dismiss" option, which will pop up a menu asking where you want to send the companion to.

[image: dismiss menu option]

Alternatively you can take another companion with you.